# how to make posibility pairing array?

Tags: algorithm, go

I have array which should return pairing posibilites. For instance, array with the [a,b] can be paired with array [b,a]. element cannot be paired with multiple other element at the same time.
here is the example:

```
ex 1: [[3,2],[2,3],[2,3]]
result -> [3,2] -> because the other cant paired in the same time

ex 2: [[1,2],[2,3],[2,1] 
result -> [1,3] || [1,2] because 1 only can paired be whether 2 or 3
```

can you help me how to implement this hope in golang ?

```
func calculateMaxPairs(n int, participants [][]int) int {
    ia := make(map[int]int)
    ib := make(map[int]int)

    for _, pair := range participants {
        a, b := pair[0], pair[1]
        ia[a]++
        ib[b]++
    }

    pairs := make(map[[2]int]struct{})
    for _, pair := range participants {
        a, b := pair[0], pair[1]
        if ia[a] == 1 && ib[b] == 1 {
            if _, foundA := ib[a]; !foundA && _, foundB := ia[b]; !foundB {
                pairs[[2]int{a, b}] = struct{}{}
            }
        }
    }

    if len(pairs) == 0 {
        var a, b int
        for k, v := range ia {
            if v == 1 {
                a = k
                break
            }
        }

        for k, v := range ib {
            if v == 1 && ia[k] == 0 {
                b = k
                break
            }
        }

        if b == 0 {
            for k, v := range ib {
                if v == 1 && ia[k] > 0 {
                    b = k
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        if a != 0 && b != 0 {
            pairs[[2]int{a, b}] = struct{}{}
        }
    }

    return len(pairs)
}
```

Comment: Hi. It's very hard to understand your constraints. Could you try to rephrase them?

Comment: Can you add some sample cases with input & output?

Comment: Hi. Your question was closed because it was judged not clear enough to be answered. But this is only temporary - if you [edit] the question to make it more clear then it can be reopened.

Comment: @Stef,

my mistake, i think it should return pairing posibilites. For instance, array with the [a,b] can be paired with array [b,a]. a element cannot be paired with multiple other element at the same time.

here is the example:
```
input :
ex 1:
[[3,2],[2,3],[2,3]] -> [3,2] -> because the other can't paired in the same time

ex 2:
[[1,2],[2,3],[2,1] -> [1,3] || [1,2] because 1 only can paired be whether 2 or 3
```

i hope these explanation and input can't make you clear

Comment: No, sorry, I still don't understand.

Comment: I notice that in all your explanations you spend more time talking about what we cannot do (for instance you said "the other can't paired" multiple times) than about what it is that we want to do. So I still don't know what it is that you want to do.

Comment: Can you perhaps try to give a bigger example?